# Calculate the sum in array with condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this

```
var input = [
  {
    type: "A",
    low: 1,
    mid: 2,
    high: 3,
  },
  {
    type: "B",
    low: 3,
    mid: 2,
    high: 0,
  },
];
```

I want to do a function that help me collect all element in that array into a new array with only 2 element with the corresponding type, and the low, mid, high will be the total of them, i've tried the function below, and it works, but it look kind of silly.

```
let resultArr = [
    {
        category: "A",
        low: 0,
        mid: 0,
        high: 0
    },
    {
        category: "B",
        low: 0,
        mid: 0,
        high: 0
    }
]
input.forEach(element => {
    if (element.type == "A") {
        resultArr[0].low += element.low
        resultArr[0].mid += element.high
        resultArr[0].high += element.high
    }
    else {
        resultArr[1].low += element.low
        resultArr[1].mid += element.high
        resultArr[1].high += element.high
    }
});

console.log(resultArr)
```

Do we have another way to make it more "professional", thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that there can be multiple elements of category A and B, and that the result array should contain only one of each with the sum of the low, mid and high values for all elements of each category? That's essentially a group by operation.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a `reduce` or `groupBy` function. Btw, it's clear and it works, man, why troubleing yourself and making it a little bit harder to maintain.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *low, mid, high will be the total of them*?

Comment: @RobG yes, that's what i'm trying to say.

Comment: @HR01M8055 I mean it will be the sum of low, mid high. looks like problem was solved, thanks to Robby

Comment: In your result array all the values are zero. But your title is "Calculate the sum in array with condition". They're not the same, so which is the actual output you want?

Comment: @Andy it just an initiating result mate, it will be changed after I run forEach function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to an intermediate object, and then get its [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const data = [{
  type: 'A',
  low: 1,
  mid: 2,
  high: 3,
}, {
  type: 'B',
  low: 3,
  mid: 2,
  high: 0,
}];

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((a, {type, low, mid, high}) => {
  a[type] = a[type] || {category: type, low: 0, mid: 0, high: 0};
  a[type].low += low;
  a[type].mid += mid;
  a[type].high += high;
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

`var newInput = input.map(ele=> ({ type: ele.type, sum: ele.low+ele.mid+ele.high }));`

This will solve the problem

Comment: Please consider there are more elements in that array.